# Import Dynamically Created Python Files

Tags: python, import

I am creating python files through the course of running a python program. I then want to import these files and run functions that were defined within them. The files I am creating are not stored within my path variables and I'd prefer to keep it that way.

Originally I was calling the `execFile(<script_path>)` function and then calling the function defined by executing the file. This has a side effect of always entering the if `__name__ == "__main__"` condition, which with my current setup I can't have happen.

I can't change the generated files, because I've already created 100's of them and don't want to have to revise them all. I can only change the file that calls the generated files.

Basically what I have now...

```
#<c:\File.py>
def func(word):
   print word

if __name__ == "__main__":
   print "must only be called from command line"
   #results in an error when called from CallingFunction.py
   input = sys.argv[1]

#<CallingFunction.py>
#results in Main Condition being called
execFile("c:\\File.py")
func("hello world")
```

Comment: Unrelated tip: never use backslashes for filenames in code.  Write "c:/file.py"; it works in Windows, and is much more consistent for everything that parses paths.

Answer (score 5):

Use

```
m = __import__("File")
```

This is essentially the same as doing

```
import File
m = File
```

Comment: It's indeed the same, and so doesn't solve Halfcent's problem if I read correctly his "files I am creating are not stored within my path variables and I'd prefer to keep it that way" remark.

Comment: Or just disregard the unhelpful constraint. The files can be put in a subpackage, out of the way of the other modules in your project's root package.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly your remarks to man that the file isn't in `sys.path` and you'd rather keep it that way, this would still work:

```
import imp

fileobj, pathname, description = imp.find_module('thefile', 'c:/')
moduleobj = imp.load_module('thefile', fileobj, pathname, description)
fileobj.close()
```

(Of course, given 'c:/thefile.py', you can extract the parts 'c:/' and 'thefile.py' with `os.path.spliy`, and from 'thefile.py' get 'thefile' with `os.path.splitext`.)